# Git - Accidentally pushed to upstream instead of my branch

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. I wanted to push my data to my branch but instead I pushed it upstream/master branch. I want revert that push. Is there any way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant to say you wanted to push your data to your fork, not branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you undo the last commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Revert locally and push your revert

```
git revert <commit_id>
git push upstream/master
```

This is better than deleting your history if you're collaborating with a team on the upstream repo. If you do hard reset and force push, you could end up removing other commits by other people. It's better to just roll back your changes and show that in the team history.

Answer (score 22):

```
git checkout -b myfeaturebranch
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push --force
```

This does the following:

1. Creates a new local branch with the commits you made
2. Goes back to the master branch
3. Resets the commit pointer back one commit
4. Pushes the reset which removes the commit from the remote

The danger here is if anyone else pulled from master those commits will be lost. In that case, you'll want to use `revert` instead of `reset` which will record the reset as part of the commit history.

```
git checkout -b myfeaturebranch
git checkout master
git revert HEAD~1
git push
```

Comment: This isn't good for team projects, you can end up removing commits by other people. It's better to push a reverted commit.

Comment: @YasserElsayed Agreed. I added that as a comment.

Comment: I got error: commit X is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed

Comment: @mononoke83, me too! we were lucky that we got the error because we were reverting a wrong commit! Long story short, it's best if you use: `git revert <commit_id>` instead of `git revert HEAD~1`

Answer (score 0):

I face this same scenario for me !

1. git revert
2. unstaged the selected files from source tree or other
3. git reset --soft HEAD~1

This makes reset the master changes into Tree in you tools.